# Linking zoom tools in Bokeh

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, bokeh

I'm working on visualizations that require very precise zooming in on X axis - down to 0.001 units, when full range can span hundreds of units.  To enable this, I'd like to use Bokeh with Spinner widgets.  Here's the minimum example where X range responds to the spinners.  Conveniently, manually entering the value into the spinner works as you would expect.

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import Spinner
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook

output_notebook()

x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
p = figure(width=400, height=200, x_range=(0, 1), y_range=(0, 1))

points = p.scatter(x=x, y=y, size=4)
spinner_xmin = Spinner(title="min X", low=0, high=1, step=0.05, value=0, width=80)
spinner_xmax = Spinner(title="max X", low=0, high=1, step=0.05, value=1, width=80)
spinner_xmin.js_link('value', p.x_range, 'start')
spinner_xmax.js_link('value', p.x_range, 'end')
show(column(p, row([spinner_xmin, spinner_xmax], width=400, sizing_mode='stretch_both')))
```

**Is there a way for the spinners to update their values when I use Bokeh's default Zoom tool, so that both tools can be used together?**

Is it easier to do in other libraries like Plotly or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the changes of the x-axis in the spinner you can simply add another `js-link` in the other direction as you did before.

Add these two lines to your code to connect the `x_range` with the spinner.

```
p.x_range.js_link('start', spinner_xmin, 'value')
p.x_range.js_link('end', spinner_xmax, 'value')
```

Now you have a two-way connection.

**Comment**

The tools don't know anything about your step-size. Therefor the values can look a litte odd. But this is also the case if you enter a value by hand.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!
No problem with step size from other zoom tools.  I can format the spinners - e.g `Spinner(... , format='0,0.000'`)